# Android App. Create checkbox from a text field

Tags: java, android, checkbox, methods

i'm new on java and android programming. What i'm trying to do is to create an app that creates a checkbox after introducing a name in an EditText field. Like creating a todo list or a shopping list.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void storeProduct(View view) {
    //Input name
    EditText productField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_field);
    String product = productField.getText().toString();
}

public void createCheckBox(String product){
    //Create Checkbox
    CheckBox savedPRoduct = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    savedProduct.setText(producto);
}
```

This is what I got so far. And I'm not sure if it's correct. I've been loocking documentation and some forums including this one and I managed to create the method storeProduct to save the string from the EditText view. Then I create the method createCheckbox that generates the checbox with the string from the EditText view. What I'm not sure is hoy to create the method that displays the checkbox created.

Any clues and info you could share with me is really appreciated.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You usually need to add view content in the file located under res/layout/R.layout.activity_main.xml

From there you can add all the view you need in your layout. Here is an example layout from the android documentation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/to" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/subject" />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="@string/message" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can do it programatically as well but I wont advice you to do so because it is against android good practice.

Comment: Well, the app is supossed to create the checkbox only when the storeProduct button is pressed. What I have in the XML file is just the EditText view and the Button view. Can you tell me why it is against android good practice?

Comment: You will end ip with a much more complicated code when in it is not needed 99% of the time. Regarding your question you can set attribute android:visibility="gone" of the checkbox before the button is pressed. You can just set the visibility of the view to visible.

Comment: Great, with that I could create one checkbox. Now I'll research a little bit to think of a loop that creates different checkboxes every time I press the button :)

Comment: I am curious why you would want to create a different checkbox everytime Someone press the button ? If I answered your question I am glad I helped and please mark this as answered :)

Comment: Well, the app is supposed to be used as a shopping list. You introduce any product you need through the EditText field. Then, once your list is created you can check everything you have thrown in your cart.

Comment: You migth want to have a look at Recycler View to display list of items ;)

Answer (score 0):

So, with the help of KevDev I managed to come up with this xml code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/product_field"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    android:hint="Product"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="storeProduct"
    android:text="Guardar"/>

<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="product"
    android:id="@+id/productCheckBox"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this java code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void storeProduct(View view) {
        //Input name
        EditText productField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.product_field);
        String product = productField.getText().toString();

        CheckBox savedProduct = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.productCheckBox);
        savedProduct.setText(product);
        savedProduct.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


}
```

It only shows a checkbox once, but i'm working to make a loop to put a series of checkboxes. I'm also looking the recyclerview documentation to introduce it in this code.